# How to override TouchUpInside event in CustomButton class?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin

I have a custom button:

```
public class CustomButton : UIButton
{
    public void HandleTouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs ea)
    {
        Console.Write("test tap"); 
    }
}
```

So i want to override TouchUpInside event in this class... how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried [what is the documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/buttons/handle_clicks/)? Particularly, `testButton1.TouchUpInside += delegate { }`.

Comment: No. I need detached custom button with touch event within

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will it work for you?

```
public class CustomButton : UIButton
{
    public CustomButton()
    {
        TouchUpInside += HandleTouchUpInside;

        // or new EventHandler(HandleTouchUpInside)
        // if Xamarin compiler/runtime doesn't allow such shorter code
    }

    public void HandleTouchUpInside(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.Write("test tap"); 
    }
}
```